# Can maven exec:java be used with an arbitrary java class from the command iine

Tags: maven

We have a few java/scala classes with `main` methods that would be useful to run via `mvn exec:java`.

Is it possible to do so **without** specifying the classes in the `pom.xml`? The examples that I have seen look like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions><execution>
    <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
  </execution></executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>some.main.MyClass</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then get executed as:

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="some.main.MyClass"
```

The intent is to be able to run

```
 mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="some.other.main.OtherClass"
```

even though it were not specified in the `pom.xml`.

When attempting to run that the error is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project sentiment: An exception occured while executing the Java class. myapp.MyMain
```

In other words the class specified on the command line is ignored in favor of the one listed in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: Where is this class? By default it seems the plugin only looks at your applications production classpath. Also, has your `.java` file been compiled into a `.class` file yet?

Comment: For the first question: the class is found *just fine* when it is the one specified in the `pom` so there's not a classpath issue. For second: well it runs fine and i would not have run this before doing `mvn package`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Documentation at https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html
says:

> If you want to execute Java programs in the same VM, you can either
>   use the command line version
>
> ```
> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" [-Dexec.args="argument1"]
> ```

This works without adding anything to your pom.

As written in the comment, this only works, if you **don't** have a configuration in your pom. If you do have a configuration in your pom, you can use a property in it, which can be overridden from the command line

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
  <executions><execution>
    <goals><goal>java</goal></goals>
  </execution></executions>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>${my.mainClass}</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and predefine the property (nested directly in `<project>`)

```
<properties>
   <my.mainClass>some.main.MyClass</my.mainClass>
</properties>
```

then you can run with

```
mvn exec:java -Dmy.mainClass="aaa.Test"
```

Comment: that was not working (or I would not have posted..) hold on i'll add details to the OP

Comment: Sorry, it was getting late yesterday.  This should work, if you _don't_ have a configuration in your pom (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4979).  If you do, you have to edit it, to explicitely use a property that you can override from the command line.

Comment: originally there were no such property - but it was not working.. i'll try again tomorrow. in any case i'll upvote for useful info (and award if can verify tomorrow)

Answer (score 1):

Looking from your usage if you are using the -Dexec.mainClass everytime, i would suggest you can get rid of the mainClass in the plugin configuration. The benefit of defining the mainClass would be to run like : mvn exec:java & it picks the main class from your defined class in pom.xml.

Once you remove the mainClass from pom.xml, you should be able to use any mainClass in the maven exec plugin usage from command line.

Comment: i had tried that initially (did not have any `mainClass` defined in the `pom.xml`

Comment: I just tried a project of mine with 2 different classes having main method and no mainClass in pom.xml. Running mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main" is working fine for me for both classes. Can you please let me know what error you get when you don't have mainClass in pom and run different classes.

Comment: oh interesting. hold on i'm trying again.